# Apache rewrite rule in Cherokee

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, cherokee

how can i use the following apache rewrite rule in cherokee?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I was trying to fix convert it like this:

```
Regex      Substitution
^/(.*)$    /index.php?$1
```

But it did not work...